# Why Expect can't work in while loop when bash executed by node.js?

Tags: node.js, while-loop, tcl, expect

I am using node.js to call my expect bash file, but Expect can't work in while loop when bash executed by node.js.

Here is my node.js code:

```
app.post("/sparknode/ssh/setssh", cors(), (req, res) => {
    shell.exec("expect /root/suanchang/set-ssh.sh", { async: false });
    res.send("success");
});
```

Here is my expect bash code written in tcl:(tcl-ssh.sh)

```
#!/bin/expect

set file "/usr/local/spark/conf/hosts.txt"
set fp [open $file r]

spawn bash -c "ssh-keygen -t rsa"
expect {
    "Overwrite (y/n)?" {
        send "y\r"
        exp_continue
    }
    "Enter file in which to save the key (/root/.ssh/id_rsa):" {
        send "\r"
        exp_continue
    }
    "Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):" {
        send "\r"
        exp_continue
    }
    "Enter same passphrase again:" {
        send "\r";
        exp_continue
    }
}
# exec touch /root/.ssh/a.txt
while {[gets $fp line]!=-1} {
     lassign [split $line " "] ip username password
     spawn bash -c "ssh-copy-id -f $username@$ip"
     expect {
        timeout { send_user "\nFailed to get password prompt\n"; exit 1 }

        "*re you sure you want to continue connecting" {
            exec touch /root/.ssh/1-arrived
            send "yes\r"
            exp_continue
        }
        "*assword*" {
            exec touch /root/.ssh/2-arrived
            send  "$password\r"
            exp_continue
        }
    }

}
```

I added two touch command in the expect block, but neither of them works. Dramatically, if I run `expect tcl-ssh.sh` directly in the node.js server, I got the correct result.

I tried to replace the expect block in the while loop with the touch command, it also works well. And below is my trial.

Not in while --- expect --- node.js exec: works well;

In while --- touch --- node.js exec: works well;

In while --- expect --- handful run: works well;

In while --- expect --- node.js exec: fault

I'm confused why this would happen.

Comment: Do `shell.exec("expect -d /root/suanchang/set-ssh.sh", ...` to enable expect's verbose debugging, and you might see what's going on.

Comment: For both the spawned ssh-keygen and ssh-copy-id expect commands, I'd suggest you add the pattern `eof` with no action block, so you don't need to wait for the timeout.

Comment: Just a nitpick. That's not bash. That's tcl - an interesting programming language since you know javascript because like javascript tcl has a built-in event loop. Which is why expect was originally written in tcl - the ability to asynchronously wait for events.

Answer (score 0):

The problem finished, and reason is quite simple:

I need to add `sudo` before `ssh` command. Thanks @glenn jackman for the debugging advice.